# How to compare json element and filter a json file in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, compare

I have a json file like below.

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "USDC",
    "name": "USD Coin",
    "decimals": "6",
    "id": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    "feeTier": "100",
    "amounts": [2499.769116, 2500.269174]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "WETH",
    "name": "Wrapped Ether",
    "decimals": "18",
    "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
    "feeTier": "3000",
    "amounts": [1.0526261272920125, 1.0590149439506866]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "USDC",
    "name": "USD Coin",
    "decimals": "6",
    "id": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    "feeTier": "500",
    "amounts": [2499.591796, 2502.09356]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "WETH",
    "name": "Wrapped Ether",
    "decimals": "18",
    "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
    "feeTier": "500",
    "amounts": [1.0551711392408099, 1.0565026582314214]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "FRAX",
    "name": "Frax",
    "decimals": "18",
    "id": "0x853d955acef822db058eb8505911ed77f175b99e",
    "feeTier": "500",
    "amounts": [2505.1101184400254, 2507.620759133425]
  }
]
```

I will compare the amounts values among those with the same name, and I want to show the ones whose first element is bigger in amounts. In the final version, other json elements will not be shown. Actually the final version will be as follows;

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "USDC",
    "name": "USD Coin",
    "decimals": "6",
    "id": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    "feeTier": "100",
    "amounts": [2499.769116, 2500.269174]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "WETH",
    "name": "Wrapped Ether",
    "decimals": "18",
    "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
    "feeTier": "3000",
    "amounts": [1.0526261272920125, 1.0590149439506866]
  },
  {
    "symbol": "FRAX",
    "name": "Frax",
    "decimals": "18",
    "id": "0x853d955acef822db058eb8505911ed77f175b99e",
    "feeTier": "500",
    "amounts": [2505.1101184400254, 2507.620759133425]
  }
]
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+object+largest+amount+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by iterating over the array of objects, grouping them by the "name" property, and then filtering each group to include only the objects where the first element of the "amounts" array is greater than the second element.

**Demo**:

```js
const filteredData = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const existing = acc.find(item => item.name === obj.name);
  if (!existing) {
    acc.push(obj);
  } else {
    const [firstAmount, secondAmount] = obj.amounts;
    const [existingFirstAmount, existingSecondAmount] = existing.amounts;
    if (firstAmount > existingFirstAmount && firstAmount > secondAmount) {
      acc = acc.filter(item => item.name !== obj.name);
      acc.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredData);
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      "symbol": "USDC",
      "name": "USD Coin",
      "decimals": "6",
      "id": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "feeTier": "100",
      "amounts": [2499.769116, 2500.269174]
    },
    {
      "symbol": "WETH",
      "name": "Wrapped Ether",
      "decimals": "18",
      "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      "feeTier": "3000",
      "amounts": [1.0526261272920125, 1.0590149439506866]
    },
    {
      "symbol": "USDC",
      "name": "USD Coin",
      "decimals": "6",
      "id": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
      "feeTier": "500",
      "amounts": [2499.591796, 2502.09356]
    },
    {
      "symbol": "WETH",
      "name": "Wrapped Ether",
      "decimals": "18",
      "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      "feeTier": "500",
      "amounts": [1.0551711392408099, 1.0565026582314214]
    },
    {
      "symbol": "FRAX",
      "name": "Frax",
      "decimals": "18",
      "id": "0x853d955acef822db058eb8505911ed77f175b99e",
      "feeTier": "500",
      "amounts": [2505.1101184400254, 2507.620759133425]
    }
  ];
</script>
```